# Windows Surface application developed using Surface sdk

Tags: c#, pixelsense

I had developed windows surface application using surface sdk. After application installed in surface device, application is work properly using stylus but touch event on button is not getting fired.

Surface list box i added events for:

```
PreviewTouchDown="OnDragSourcePreviewTouchDown"
SelectionChanged="DragSource_SelectionChanged"
```

I developed application using Surface Application (WPF) version 2.0 in windows 7 OS. and device having windows RT OS.

Comment: Please provide more detailed information about your problem, your current statement is not sufficient to deduce anything.

Comment: In surface listbox, i added images and written events for PreviewTouchDown, SelectionChanged. It does works using stylus pen, but touch on image is not working